# How to extract single tag from tags row ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, analysis

[image]

3300 rows

I need make new single column with single tag each row

Comment: Don't share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors. We're going to need more information than this. What is that data, where is it coming from? You obviously haven't read the Pandas docs, please do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (pandas 0.25+) with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column `Tags` for lists:

```
df1 = (df.assign(Tags = df['Tags'].str.strip('><').str.split('><'))
         .explode('Tags')
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split and then explode your dataframe.

```
df['Tags'] = df['Tags'].astype('str')

for i in range(len(df)):
     df.at[i, 'Tags'] = df[i, df['Tags'].strip('><').split('><')]

df.explode('Tags')
```

Comment: Your solution not running